# Radio Buttons inside expandable list remain when expanding other child elements

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group, expandablelistadapter

I want to make an expandable list of radio groups in my android app. each element of the list should contain (when opened) several individual radio groups. So far I am testing with only one radiogroup per child and already I am encountering a problem I can't seem to solve by myself.

When I expand a parent of my expandable list, it seems to work properly. The radiobuttons of a radiogroup (which is the only child element of a parent right now) are displayed the way they should. However, when I expand another parent of my expandable list, the radio buttons are added to the already existing buttons of the other child group. Which means: Once I've expanded several child groups, each one of the expanded children contains tons of radio buttons, flooding the whole screen.
Simply put, when I expand parent 1 I get the choices

- yes
- no
- maybe

When I expand the second parent, I get the radio choices

- yes
- no
- maybe
- yes
- no
- perhaps
- probably

... which are also added to the radio button group thats inside parent 1. So now I have 2 large expanded list elements. When I expand another group, the choices get added to all the child views as well, and so on, and so on...

So, following simple logic it seems that all the radio buttons are not put into a new group (thats newly created every time I expand a child list), but instead they are added to the same, already existing group.

I have been able to pretty much isolate the problem to the getChildView function inside my ExpandableListAdapter class. This is the code which causes the output described above:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    ExpandListChild child = (ExpandListChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);
    }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> inputDetailsList = child.getInputfields();
    //RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(view.getContext());
    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    int has_radiogroup = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <inputDetailsList.size(); i++){
        if (inputDetailsList.get(i).get("type").equals("radio")){
            has_radiogroup = 1;
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(rg.getContext());
            rb.setText(inputDetailsList.get(i).get("textcontent"));
            rg.addView(rb);
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

Here is the xml file that is used as child layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:background="@color/ExpandChildBackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvChild"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="17dip" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

The line where I suspect my error could be this one:

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
```

It looks for the radio group I created inside the inflated child layout (R.layout.child_layout). But it does not use a new one for each expanded child view and instead uses an existing one to apply the buttons to. In other words, it seems like the radio group never gets the sign that its "finished" and/or the child view never gets the sign that a new radioGroup has to be used instead of the old one.

What I have tried is creating a new RadioGroup for each child view using the following line (you can see it is the commented line in the code above), instead of using the radiogroup I defined in my layout.
Making a fresh radiogroup would look like this:

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(view.getContext());
```

However, this does not work, it does not display any radio groups, let alone buttons at all. I have also tried removing the radiogroup element from the layout xml-file (because its not used anyway). Still no luck. Using simple unorganized textviews for each element seems to work properly, so this points to a problem with my radio group implementation as well.

Honestly, I am out of ideas right now. I might be getting the wrong context, but I have no clue what context to use. If anyone is able to point me the right direction, I would be extremely grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I have been able to fix the problem myself. I have simply removed the if-condition [ `if (view == null)` ], so the new code looks like this:

```
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    ExpandListChild child = (ExpandListChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> inputDetailsList = child.getInputfields();

    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    int has_radiogroup = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <inputDetailsList.size(); i++){

        if (inputDetailsList.get(i).get("type").equals("radio")){
            System.out.println("type: "+inputDetailsList.get(i).get("type"));
            has_radiogroup = 1;
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(rg.getContext());
            rb.setText(inputDetailsList.get(i).get("textcontent"));
            System.out.println("textcontent: "+inputDetailsList.get(i).get("textcontent"));
            rb.setId(Integer.parseInt(inputDetailsList.get(i).get("value")));

            if (has_radiogroup == 1){
                rg.addView(rb);
            }
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

Now it makes sense. The `LayoutInflater` is called everytime a new child view is generated, i.e. a group is expanded. Before this, it just used the existing view (view was not null) that was filled with `radiobuttons`, and added the new `radiobuttons` to that existing view, resulting in my list flooding the screen.

Thanks however to anyone trying to get their heads into the problem.

Comment: This solution is not working for me...I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me.
For **RadioButtons and CheckBoxs**

```
        android:focusable="false"
```